# Restore part of a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

We have a legacy system with a shaky admin interface and one of the users managed to wipe out some records. We have a backup from a few days ago but we *don't* want to just remove the DB and restore from the backup - I only need a few types of objects from there (lots of rows, but only a few associated objects).

How can I restore only some records? I thought the following would work:

- `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` to connect to the backup db
- Grab the records I want to restore (e.g. `widgets = Widget.all`)
- Change the connection to the production db (again with `establish_connection`)
- Save the widgets (`widgets.save`) - but it doesn't work?

Is there something intrinsic in an ActiveRecord object that I can change to make it save with the same id and everything to the `production` database, even though it's originally from the `backup` database, so they are pretty much identical to how they were before (apart from the `created_at`, of course, which is ok)

This is probably not the best way to do it, but I can't really determine what the best way is. The database is fairly hefty so I can't really get raw sql or something like that.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "The database is fairly hefty so I can't really get raw sql or something like that."  What do you mean?

Comment: You can pipe a db to a giant sql statement that contains the data in the db, which executes the commands necessary to restore the data. But the db is too big to go crawling through all that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

I believe the easiest approach would be to take a snapshot of the few tables that you want to restore and then, restore that backup to your target database.

**Approach 2**

If you cannot take a backup just try to restore the existing backup to a new database and then, connect to it using ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection then, select records of those few tables and restore that to your target database.

**Approach 3**

If you are using mysql or any other RDBMS then, just restore the back up to a new database and then, write SQL to transfer table rows from that database to your target database.

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing #1. All is well! (and we are changing that interface STAT)